# Как вернуть изначальные Items в Listbox после поиска

Tags: c#

У меня проходит поиск по параметрам, выбираются нужные элементы. Как мне вернуть то, что было до поиска?

Comment: код в студию.

Answer (score 1):

1. Использовать два списка, первый полный, второй для отображения в ListView. Искать в первом, выводить во второй;
2. Использовать TreeView, который умеет скрывать элементы списка;
3. Сделать свой объект со свойством отображения, переписать отрисовку ListView;

Последний вариант, как мне кажется, более правильный.